# video is saving but showing 0 KB only. What is the probable error in these code of OpenCv

Tags: python-2.7, video-processing, opencv3.0

I am trying to save video using videocapture object in openCv using python. But after pressing 'q' the video is saved as 'output.avi' but its size is showing as 0 KB. Need your help, not able to find out the error.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#1.2. Gui Features in OpenCV 25
#OpenCV-Python Tutorials Documentation, Release 1
# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)
# write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Its the issue with Codics type.you need to check which codics works properly with the given media type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to play with fourCC code

FourCC code is passed as cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G') or cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG) for MJPG.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
#fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'DIVX')
#out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', -1, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For more read,  [OpenCV saving doc](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#saving-a-video) and [FourCC doc](http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php)

Comment: Can you explain me a bit, what '-1' signifies?? And why you have have commented my first statement?

Comment: @AjayKhetan FourCC is a 4-byte code used to specify the video codec. here I have not send any codec. You can try other format and see the result

Answer (score 0):

It maybe that the `codecs` for `XVID` is not properly installed.

(If you are using Jupyter Notebook, there would be jupyter logs begin with `OpenCV: FFMPEG: ...`)

If you are on linux, you could try to use the `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')` as below:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', -1, 20.0, (640,480))
```

Notice, **the extension `mp4` matters**! Should choose the right extension matching the `codec`.